# DMARC, DKIM, or SPF? Emails going into quarantine

Tags: spam, spf, dkim, dmarc

I have never had to deal with DKIM, DMARC, or SPF records before; however, our SPF record is full (10, Cloudflare) and I have a vendor whose emails aren’t making it to our mailboxes. 
I made exceptions in our spam filter for the emails, and have added DNS TXT records to bypass these issue, but they are still landing in the O365 quarantine.

I believe adding them to our SPF record would resolve the issue, but I am starting to think it is a DMARC issue.

What do I need to do?

Below is a part of the header.

```
Authentication-Results: spf=pass (sender IP is 13.111.207.78)
smtp.mailfrom=bounce.relay.corestream.com; mcneese.edu; dkim=none (message not 
signed) header.d=none;mcneese.edu; dmarc=none action=none 
header.from=mcneese.edu;compauth=fail reason=601
```

Comment: I don't think there is issue with spf- it said pass, but with dkim, the message was not signed (dkim=none (message not signed)). Try signing the message

Comment: How would i sign a message? This is completely new to me :/

Comment: If the message is being sent from your server to another, the message has to be signed with DKIM, then you should set up you mailer to sign these messages (for example postfix with opendkim). I don't think I understand your issue clearly, but if it is the other way around, you need to consult the sender to sign their emails. SPF record is for your domain to say which mail servers are allowed to send messages with this domain name to clarify.

Comment: I may be impossible to determine from the receiving side, but certainly without the full headers we really have no idea what is going on, as you can see with commenters here just trying to guess.